# Append multiple PDF files - follow-up

Tags: pdf, applescript, automator

New user here and have a follow-up query from the original post at:
[Append multiple PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000566/append-multiple-pdf-files)

Firstly the solution given by Jerry Stratton on this thread is amazing and just the sort of thing I have been looking for, so thanks for this info.

I have tried to make an edit to suit my own project but am running into some issues.

I'd like to be able to set the Application to overwrite the 'changing' PDF once the cover page is prepended.

The **Move Finder Items** gives the option to Replace Existing File (screenshot attached) but rather than overwrite the file, it just generates a new file with a random name.

Any thoughts?

I am a complete novice scripting-wise but I am buzzing at the potential here to improve some of my workflows, any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: If you are using the `Combine PDF Pages` action, you can see in its result that those random named files are what it outputs.  The files will still need to be renamed.

Comment: Thanks red_menace, as per the original post I set a Value of Variable applescript to rename the output with the existing name, which worked a peach until I try to overwrite it and then it reverts to the random name. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong